# How to remove previous versions of .NET Core from Linux (CentOS 7.1)

Tags: asp.net, linux, asp.net-core, .net-core, coreclr

I would like to install the current version Core 1.0. Currently the RC2 version is installed. [The instruction on the official website are](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#centos):

> Before you start, please remove any previous versions of .NET Core
>   from your system.

But I don't know how and I can't find nothing from Microsoft like for example [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc2-to-rtm.html).

I found this [script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/cli/rel/1.0.0/scripts/obtain/uninstall/dotnet-uninstall-pkgs.sh)... but my Linux skills are not great and I won't make it worst.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes it can be so simple! 
In order to remove the previous installation, simply remove the dotnet folder from where you installed it on disk.

Big Thanks to [Zlatko Knezevic](https://github.com/blackdwarf)

Comment: facing permission issue in this way

Answer (score 50):

You need to do this over the package manager, otherwise, you end up with a broken system.

This is for **Ubuntu/Debian/Mint**:

To list all installed packages

```
sudo apt --installed list
```

To list all the packages you installed

```
sudo apt --installed list | grep "dotnet-dev"
```

to remove a specific package

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge PACKAGE_NAME
```

e.g.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge dotnet-dev-1.0.1
```

For other distros, consult the [Packman-Rosetta-Stone](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta)

Comment: Ok, this make sense, but what if i install it via dotnet-install.sh ? how i can uninstall it or update?

Comment: Command does not run on 22.04

Answer (score 8):

In CentOS you would do the following:

**1 - Find the package installed**

```
yum list installed | grep "aspnet"
```

**2 - Remove the package**

```
yum remove aspnetcore-store-2.0.0.x86_64
```

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu:

First list the dotnet packages installed:

```
$ sudo apt --installed list | grep "dotnet"
```

You'll have a result like this:

```
dotnet-apphost-pack-3.0    dotnet-hostfxr-3.1         dotnet-runtime-deps-5.0
dotnet-apphost-pack-3.1    dotnet-hostfxr-5.0         dotnet-sdk-5.0
dotnet-apphost-pack-5.0    dotnet-runtime-5.0         dotnet-targeting-pack-3.0
dotnet-host                dotnet-runtime-deps-2.2    dotnet-targeting-pack-3.1
dotnet-hostfxr-2.2         dotnet-runtime-deps-3.0    dotnet-targeting-pack-5.0
dotnet-hostfxr-3.0         dotnet-runtime-deps-3.1
```

To uninstall the packages of linked to version 3 for example just type:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge dotnet-*3*
```

Comment: That commmand does not run on 22.04

Comment: @Greg apt command on Ubuntu? Are you sure? That's a first

Comment: sudo apt --installed list | grep "dotnet"   Does Not Run on Ubuntu 22.04 for me.

Comment: Whats the error?

Answer (score 3):

For any CentOS users, the yum command is used to install/uninstall packages, here is how you do it in CentOS:

```
yum remove dotnet-sdk-2.0.0
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?tabs=linux for Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I found on MSDN and It worked for me as charm.
First list the install SDKs using below command

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

Then run below set of commands after updating version as found in above command.

```
version="1.0.1"
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr/$version
```

Answer (score 1):

Today I was uninstalling old version of dotnet on my Linux Mint. First I typed:

```
$ sudo apt remove dotnet
```

Then I pressed tab. It showed all related packages. I simply copied them and pasted:

```
$ sudo apt remove dotnet-host dotnet-runtime-2.2 dotnet-sdk-2.2 dotnet-hostfxr-2.2 dotnet-runtime-deps-2.2
```

I guess in Fedora/CentOS, the procedure is same. Just use `yum` instead of `apt`. I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to remove all dotnet versions:

1- List all dotnet packages

```
sudo apt — installed list | grep "dotnet"
```

2- Remove them one by one. Change this list according to the output command of step 1:

Change this list according to the output command of step 1.

```
sudo apt-get remove - purge -y dotnet-host 
sudo apt-get remove - purge -y dotnet-hostfxr-5.0 
sudo apt-get remove - purge -y dotnet-runtime-5.0 
sudo apt-get remove - purge -y dotnet-runtime-deps-5.0 
sudo apt-get remove - purge -y dotnet-sdk-5.0
sudo apt-get remove - purge -y dotnet-targeting-pack-5.0 
sudo apt-get remove - purge -y dotnet-apphost-pack-5.0 
sudo apt-get remove - purge -y dotnet-runtime-6.0 
sudo apt-get remove - purge -y dotnet-hostfxr-6.0
sudo apt-get remove - purge -y dotnet-runtime-deps-6.0 
sudo apt-get remove - purge -y dotnet-targeting-pack-6.0
sudo apt-get remove --purge -y dotnet-apphost-pack-6.0
sudo apt-get remove --purge -y dotnet-host/now 6.0.0
sudo apt-get remove - purge -y dotnet-apphost-pack-6.0
```

My article link about this: https://medium.com/@alperonline/how-to-uninstall-dotnet-from-ubuntu-c42b9c016ec9